# What if imbalanced processing methods doesn't work

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

The current problem I meet is the classification results are **NOT GOOD** even I used many imbalanced processing techniques such as `resampling`, `smote`, `cost-learning`.

Specifically, I have a dataset, **difficult** and **easy** are 2 classes in my dataset. While classes distribution is serve imbalanced (**difficult:easy = 187:13**) in my dataset.

I use `random forest` to train my model and evaluate it by using `10-fold cross validation`, then results is on line "no strategy".

Then I use some techniques to process this imbalanced issue, but I can only get very low experimental results as follows("cost-sensitive", "smote", "resampling"), some values are even lower than 0.1.

```
Methods            P(d)  R(d)  F(d)  P(e)  R(e)  F(e)  Acc 
-------------------------------------------------------------
no strategy        0.000 0.000 0.000 0.935 0.995 0.964 0.930
cost-sensitive     0.500 0.077 0.133 0.939 0.995 0.966 0.935 
smote              0.500 0.077 0.133 0.939 0.995 0.966 0.935
resampling         0.500 0.077 0.133 0.939 0.995 0.966 0.935
```

How can I improve my results or is any other advanced techniques? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It seems that `sampling`, `cost-sensitive learning` are not suite for me, and I don't want to use `anomaly detection` to find the outlier :(

Comment: P, R, and F above mean precision, recall, and F-measure, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to optimize for? If it's precision or recall, you can also try changing the probability threshold (i.e. instead of using >0.5 to call something as 'easy', you could use for example >0.2). Play with it and see what the best threshold is using CV.

Another option is to use undersampling of the most common class. So with a CV fold, create many 'folds' that contain all values from them 'easy' category and a few from the 'difficult' category so that they are balanced. Train a model on all these 'folds' and then use them all to predict on the actual CV-fold in an ensemble-manner.

Comment: Firstly, I try to optimize the above values(i.e., precision, recall, F-measure), and the threshold cannot be modified T T . Secondly, do you have some suggestions for some better _undersampling_ methods?

Comment: Why can't the threshold be modified? There are quite a few undersampling method in literature, so just check what's available in your programming language.

Comment: your second options quite looks like the `EasyEnsmble` algorithm, So do you know other specific algorithm name of these methods (like oversampling, cost-sensitive learning, active liearning, and kernel-based.)

Comment: I've never heard the term 'EasyEnsemble' but you could try that one.

Comment: Maybe it will works, who knows :) Thanks all the same.

Comment: @Stergios  Could you please answer this question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32812/categorization-of-approaches-to-deal-with-imbalanced-classes Thanks.